# Curl request with comma in the directory name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, post

I have problem to execute curl request in the directory has comma in the name using bash command line.

```
curl --request POST --form "file=@$PWD/input_file" http://HOSTURL.com > output_file
```

if the directory name is

"test" works

"test test" works

"test, test" doesn't work.

I tried many ways to escape characters like quotations, back slush, changing IFS... but still getting error "failed creating formpost data".
Could someone advise how I should treat such directory names?

Comment: This is a curl question, not a bash question -- bash is passing the comma to curl just fine; it's curl (which isn't part of bash) that's misinterpreting it.

Comment: BTW, why pass `"$PWD"` at all? It *is* the local directory, so it's what `curl` will be evaluating a relative path in context of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case `curl` isn't designed to handle. However, by passing the filename on stdin, you can avoid needing it to correctly parse that value at all.

```
curl --request POST --form "file=@-" http://HOSTURL.com <input_file >output_file
```

Comment: Yes this solved thank you very much. I thought I need the absolute path to send.